# Why won't JSON accept my PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I can't get the `jQuery.ajax` call to use my PHP string variable `$defaultTicker`.  I have tried encoding to utf8 and trimming any type of "special" characters, yet nothing has helped.  If I view the page source, I see a valid JSON array: `{ "ticker":"SPY", "startDay":1, "endDay":30}`.

Here is my jQuery to submit the data:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "findCorrelated.php",
     // WHY DOESN'T <?=$defaultTicker?> work???
     data: {
         "ticker": "<?=$defaultTicker?>",
         "startDay": 1,
         "endDay": 30
     },
     success: function (data) {
         $('#testParagraph').show();
         $('#testParagraph').html(data);
     }
 });
```

Any ideas as to why it is failing to submit using the PHP variable?  If I hardcode `SPY` in place of `<?defaultTicker?>`, it will succeed.  However, when viewing the source, the results appear to be the same.

Note: I am not using `json_encode` on a PHP array, because the `startDay` and `endDay` values are going to come from the client-side JavaScript.

Edit:  The real issue was actually with my browser settings in Chrome.  It was caching my javascript and ignoring any updates to the files, so I kept making changes and getting the same results.

Comment: That's not JSON. That's just a normal JavaScript Object.

Comment: If printing `$defaultTicker` and printing `SPY` both result in the same output, then the problem is somewhere else.  (Having said that, are you _sure_ they result in the same output?)  Have you opened a console (`[F12]` in most browsers) and debugged your javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your server does not have [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration enabled.

Because of that, the following line is not parsed as PHP code, but rather it's considered as plain text.

```
"ticker": "<?=$defaultTicker?>",
```

Use this instead:

```
"ticker": "<?php echo $defaultTicker; ?>"
```

Short tags are considered a PITA in the coding world, because if you ever have to migrate your code to a server that doesn't support it, or you can't enable it, than you have to edit all your code just for that environment when you could have just gone with normal tags. *However*, as of 5.4.x, short hand tags are enabled by *default* and parsed in any PHP document. But it's good to keep in mind different environments.

Comment: Thanks, I did need to turn on the short tag options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
data: { "ticker":"<?php echo $defaultTicker; ?>", "startDay":1, "endDay":30},
```

instead of:

```
data: { "ticker":"<?=$defaultTicker?>", "startDay":1, "endDay":30},
```